# Source multiple r scripts from github

Tags: r, github

I usually use some personal functions during my r sessions, as:

```
s1<-"https://github.com/juanchiem/R-sources-Juan/blob/master/rend_aj.R?raw=TRUE" # rend_aj.R
s2<-"https://github.com/juanchiem/R-sources/blob/master/theme_juan.R?raw=TRUE" # theme_juan.R
s3<-"https://github.com/juanchiem/R-sources-Juan/blob/master/assumptions.R?raw=TRUE" # lm_assumptions.R

devtools::source_url(s1)
devtools::source_url(s2)
devtools::source_url(s3)
```

I wonder if Is it possible to create a function to source these 3 files from github directly by their file names (detailed after #)
Thanks!

Comment: Why not get the exact raw file url and use `wget`/`curl` or any other tool(e.g `m(M)ap`ping the devtools call)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could write up a custom function(see note below) to achieve the goal:

```
custom_source <- function(repo_name,repo_branch,name,
                          ...){

  url_to_use <- paste0("https://github.com/",repo_name,
                        "/blob/",repo_branch,"/",name,".R",
                       "?raw=TRUE"
                       )
  devtools::source_url(url_to_use,...)
}
```

Calling the function(you could include this in the same function above but I prefer calling it individually)

```
invisible(Map(function(x) custom_source("juanchiem/R-sources-Juan",
               "master",x), c("rend_aj","theme_juan", "lm_assumptions")))
```

Result(truncated):

```
  SHA-1 hash of file is 586d156021371098ec51c35c4c056d7c98a94d3d
SHA-1 hash of file is 5c84c1e8e7bd4fe9bf6cd26c4f5e955c20cf851b
SHA-1 hash of file is 63790352a1dc712611bbd26a67cd33d2d1ce5b2c
```

**NOTE**:

1. This will only download `.R` files. Can modify as needed.
2. `invisible` is used to suppress printing to console. However, adding `echo=FALSE` or `verbose=FALSE` should have suppressed the output but it doesn't.

Comment: Do you notice that when you call the three files at once, all the code functions are printed in the console, and not  when calling them individually..

Comment: Yes, I just experimented with merely using `source` instead of `source_url` and it works(`devtools` uses `base` `source` but also provides the `SHA` code).  Add `echo=FALSE` to turn it off.

Comment: sorry, where should I inlcude `echo=FALSE`

Comment: I have edited. Please see note 2. I think it might be an issue with `Map`'s print method overriding that of source(`purrr`'s `map` also prints).